# I lost my React project, but I built it, and I have the 'dist' folder that I uploaded to hosting

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a React project, built it, and uploaded everything to hosting. However, I forgot to push it to my GitHub, and my repository is very outdated. By mistake, I lost the entire project, and now I don't have the latest version.

I want to try and see if there's a possibility of recreating the React project using the 'dist' folder and the files I uploaded to hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, but unfortunately, that is impossible.
Dist folders are the build conversions of your project and can't be converted back to a dev folder.